# Android WebView downloading then displaying later in AlertDialog

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am currently trying to display a webview in a small popup. But I would like to first load the view, then display it when properly available.

So what I tried to do was 2 functions:

```
public void fetchPopUp(String url, Context appContext)
{
    webView = new WebView(appContext);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

public void displayPopUp(Activity activity)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    }

    builder.setView(webView);
    AlertDialog dial = builder.show();
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new TCWebAppInterface(dial, webView, activity), "WAIAndroid");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:WAIAndroid.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
    }
```

As for the WAIAndroid resize:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height)
{
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.e("JIBA", "sizes\n" + activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels + "\n" + height + "\n" + activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + "\n" + activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
    });
}
```

The **strange thing** is when I call both fetchPopup and displayPopup one after the other, it's working perfectly (beside size issue which was the point of the resize).

But when I call them separately, the popup display empty and the resize method is not called.

I tried to display every objects, the webview is still the good, I tried displaying when it's finished loading, it's called properly, I tried reloading, tried to make it invisible or gone then visible again, tried to reload in javascript. Nothing changes the fact that when I call the `displayPop` a bit later than right after the `fetchPopup` method, it doesn't work. I guessed that there's an issue after the url is loaded and "`onPageFinished`" is called. But I can't find how to work around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm running out of ideas!

Thanks a lot SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new TCWebAppInterface(dial, webView, activity), "WAIAndroid");
```

to your fetchPopUp function before loadUrl, like this:

```
public void fetchPopUp(String url, Context appContext){
    webView = new WebView(appContext);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new TCWebAppInterface(dial, webView, activity), "WAIAndroid");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Strangely, like this, the resize is never called at all.

Comment: My bad, made I mistake in the code, but in fact, like this the resize is called properly indeed. (But the popup still don't display the webview when called the displaypopup function later than right after)

Comment: As long as I can resize manually, I just have to find how to do it dynamically. Thanks a lot :)